# What is performance measure in encog and how can I get weights?

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, encog

I'm using neural network of Encog-core-cs (.net version). I want to know about measures of performance and weights of edges in neural network.

What are the performance measures that we can report? How are training and validation error calculated? Are there any other performance measures? What is measure of termination? How can I find the weights of connections in network?

In case of factory version:

```
 var model=new EncogModel(data);
 model.selectMethod(data,MLMethodFactory.TypeFeedforward);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only answer the last part of your question which is "How can i found weights of connections in network"

well there are couple of ways. the first is network.GetWeight() method which returns the weight between two layers (i never used it before) and the second is
network.Flat.Weights property which return double[] contains all weights

Comment: another possibility is network.DumpWeights() method which returns string of weights separated with cooma

Comment: Tnx. what about factory version?{   var model=new EncogModel(data); model.selectMethod(data,MLMethodFactory.TypeFeedforward);   }